# Get Custom Field Name ( Label or Key ) Not Value

Tags: custom-field

I have the custom field value but i also need the name or what some call the label or key to print on the frontend.

```
get_post_meta('get_the_ID(), 'key', true );
```

How to get the name or key instead of the value?

I'm NOT using ACF as i know they have a plugin specific function for this, i am only using WordPress custom fields.

I don't want to use this ACF function

```
get_field_object
```

I want to use a WordPress function which does the same thing so the output will be :

```
name : value
```

I have the value from get_post_meta but how do i get the name?

Comment: `get_post_meta(get_the_ID());` will return all the meta details in an array. You can get your key from there.

Comment: I need the key for each specific custom field.

Comment: Where are you defining the label to begin with? How are you adding the fields?

Comment: I'm only using get_post_meta but i need to add the label which is the key or custom field name, beside the value and don;t want to hard code it, would rather use PHP to add the name. I'm asking how to get the label.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - in your first example you already have the key, it's `'key'`... You don't need a function to return it as it's already readily available. As Abhik metions, you can also omit the `$key` argument to retrieve an associative array mapping keys to values for all meta on the post.

Comment: I want to print the key ( custom field name ) using PHP. I don't want to hard code the key in HTML